# How to get Tab from nsIDOMWindow?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

A noob at firefox extension development here. Is there a way to find Tab object from a given nsIDOMWindow?

```
let wm = Cc['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);

var windowListener =
{
  onOpenWindow: function(aWindow)
  {
    // Wait for the window to finish loading
    let domWindow = aWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);

    domWindow.addEventListener("load", function()
    {
      domWindow.removeEventListener("load", arguments.callee, false);

      if (domWindow.document.documentElement.getAttribute("windowtype") == "navigator:browser")
      {

        // how do I find tabs?

      }
    }, false);
  },
}

wm.addListener(windowListener);
```

Been trying to find the documentation on MDN with no luck, mozilla #extdev channel gives me no response either :(

Comment: require('sdk/model/core').modelFor(), see [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29329183/125562)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current tab you can do:

```
domWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab
```

To get the set of all tabs you can use:

```
domWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer
```

In here you can use [tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/tabs#m-getItemAtIndex) methods to select a specific index, etc.
You can see more information in [tabbrowser - XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/tabbrowser), [Tabbed browser - Code Snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) and

Comment: was hoping to be able to do this using bootstrapped extension but I can't find any reference to it.. Will revert back to xul-based extension. Thanks

Comment: not sure it was possible at that time, but these days there's the add-on SDK (with a high-level and a low-level APIs) that allows accessing tabs.