# How to add a Progress Listener to a tab object from Addon SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I'd like to get URL change notification (not load ones).
There is [an API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners), but I don't understand how to use in context of [Addon SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK), which treats tabs [in its own way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs).

1. How to install a listener to an SDK tab?
2. How to convert [nsiDOMWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMWindow) from [a progress object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWebProgress) to SDK tab?

Related:

- [How to get Tab from nsIDOMWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310570/how-to-get-tab-from-nsidomwindow)

Answer (score 2):

To install a listener, convert SDK tab to its raw (old) representation using viewFor.
Backward conversion is possible with modelFor and getTabForContentWindow.

```
const tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
const {viewFor} = require('sdk/view/core');
const {modelFor} = require('sdk/model/core');
const {getBrowserForTab, getTabForContentWindow} = require("sdk/tabs/utils");
const {Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm", this);

var progressListener = {
QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIWebProgressListener, Ci.nsISupportsWeakReference]),
    onLocationChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aURI) {
        var highLevel= modelFor(getTabForContentWindow(aProgress.DOMWindow));
        console.log("onLocationChange ", highLevel.url);
    }
};

tabs.on('open', function(newTab) {
    var lowLevel = viewFor(newTab);
    var browser = getBrowserForTab(lowLevel);
    browser.addProgressListener(progressListener);
});
```

Inspired by
[Converting to chrome windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows#Converting_to_chrome_windows)

Comment: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIWebProgress.addProgressListener]"

Comment: I'm trying to get the tab object from within the location change function, to attach content scripts and workers to the listeners. Would you know how to it?

Comment: highLevel variable in example contains tab object.